# Rewrite rules for WordPress

Tags: apache, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a custom page on my theme that displays differently based on given parameters. This page is set as homepage for the website.
Valid parameters combinations can be as follows:

```
my_domain/?fa={action}&type={type}
my_domain/?fa={action}&id={type}
my_domain/?fa={action}
```

What i'm trying to do is to convert these links to the following:

```
my_domain/fa/{action}/type/{type}
my_domain//fa/{action}/id/{type}
my_domain/fa/{action}
```

My .htaccess file now looks like this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^fa/(.*)/type/(.*)$ /index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^fa/(.*)/id/(.*)$ /index.php?fa=$1&fid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^fa/(.*)$ /index.php?fa=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

What am i doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Radu

Answer (score 1):

same issue, I used a class created by 'Kyle E Gentile' lost the link.

but his class is below.
create a file: add_rewrite_rules.php

```
//prevent duplicate loading of the class if you are using this in multiply plugins
if(!class_exists('add_rewrite_rules')){

    class Add_rewrite_rules{

        var $query_vars;
        var $rules;

        function __construct($options){
            $this->init($options);
        }

        function init($options){
            foreach($options as $key => $value){
                $this->$key = $value;
            }
        }

        function rules_exist(){
            global $wp_rewrite;

            $has_rules = TRUE;

            foreach($this->rules as $key => $value){
                if(!in_array($value, $wp_rewrite->rules)){
                    $has_rules = FALSE;
                }   
            }

            return $has_rules;
        }

        //to be used add_action with the hook 'wp_head'
        //flushing rewrite rules is labor intense so we better test to see if our rules exist first
        //if the rules don't exist flush its like after a night of drinking  
        function flush_rules(){
            global $wp_rewrite;

            if(!$this->rules_exist()){
                //echo "flushed"; // If want to see this in action uncomment this line and remove this text and you will see it flushed before your eyes
                $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
            }
        }

        //filter function to be used with add_filter() with the hook "query_vars"
        function add_query_vars($query_vars){

            foreach($this->query_vars as $var){
                $query_vars[] = $var;
            }

            return $query_vars;
        }

        //to be used with a the add_action() with the hook "generate_rewrite_rules"
        function add_rewrite_rules(){
            global $wp_rewrite;

            $wp_rewrite->rules = $this->rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
        }

    }

}
```

then in your funcitons.php file,

```
//-------------------------------------------------
//ADDING REWRITE RULES AND QUERY VARS
//-------------------------------------------------
include('add_rewrite_rules.php');
$options = array(
        'query_vars' => array('fa', 'type'),
        'rules' => 
            array(
                '(.+?)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&fa=$matches[2]&type=$matches[3]'
            )
    );
$rewrite = new Add_rewrite_rules($options);
add_action('wp_head', array(&$rewrite, 'flush_rules'));
add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', array(&$rewrite, 'add_rewrite_rules') );
add_filter( 'query_vars', array(&$rewrite, 'add_query_vars') );
//-------------------------------------------------
//ADDING REWRITE RULES AND QUERY VARS
//-------------------------------------------------
```

could be worth looking into.. 
i know it will work for your first two variables, fa & type but..
not sure if you could re-write a little to add the ID,

Marty