# Using $_POST data after wordpress url rewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

My permalink structure is set so I have **url.com/page**

I made a basic PHP script prior to installing wordpress that uses $_POST data to display the correct set of information, so the base would look like **url.com/work.php?featured=print**

After adding this to my Wordpress installation with the rewrite from the permalink structure above, the link actually works as:
**url.com/work/?featured=print**

I'm having trouble getting the extra rewrite to work so that a clean **url.com/work/print** will work properly.

This is what my .htaccess file looks like, I appended the last line before the end IfModule tag hoping that would take anything **work/[page]/** and direct it to **work/?featured=[page]**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php
RewriteRule ^work/([^/.]+)/?$ work/?featured=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

any help?

**EDIT**

Discovered rewrite via the functions page and found this quite resourceful

[Rewrite rules for WordPress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360205/rewrite-rules-for-wordpress)

however, my rule is taking **.com/work/print** (work/?feat=print) and simply showing it as **.com/work** without the page data being passed through

```
'work/([^/]+)/?$' => 'work&feat=$matches[1]'
```

The above is the only thing I changed from post I just referenced. I tried keeping is specific to get it to work first to avoid any loose ends...
Still not working properly though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.rlmseo.com/blog/passing-get-query-string-parameters-in-wordpress-url/

For some reason, couldn't get anything to work, but ^ is quite simple and worked great

Answer (score 0):

The wp-admin dashboard has a tool that helps with the rewrites. When I ran a few WP sites, I used it to achieve what I wanted. Did you try that first?

Comment: Yup! only issue is I'm trying to rewrite page data that doesn't process through Wordpress's rewrite

Comment: Page data? Rewrites are for the url. I did a lot of validation and work inside WP's header.php file and if it's in WP at all, you can work it there. My problem was how WP would let any info go in the middle of the url yet still get to a page. So I'd test in the header which page it thought it was and compare the proper url against the existing one and then go to the proper url if different.

Comment: Oh, I thought the wordpress rewrite was strictly for Wordpress data being passed through. The correct URL after the wordpress rewrite is work/?featured=print as the print is what's being passed through as the $_POST data

Comment: I'm still confused by how you say "Wordpress data". `$_POST` is just the next page the visitor is browsing to. I believe you need to look more deeply into tools available in the dashboard (and/or via plug-ins) rather than hacking `.htaccess`. I also started looking at `.htaccess` before learning how the dashboard worked.

Comment: /%year%/%monthnum%/%category%/%postname%/   if im not mistaken thats wordpress data

Comment: The dashboard rewrite can also use (and mix) slug and post id.

Comment: Hm alright. I also just found out about wp_rewrite which im trying to research to do now, i guess thats hte proper way to do it.

Comment: Have you done so by adding rewrite rules in the functions file? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9360205/rewrite-rules-for-wordpress I'm just using that but modified, not getting a 404 anymore, but it's not appending the post data... work/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=work&feat=$matches[1]'